# How to return an array to twig in symfony2 and how to use it?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.6

I have written an action in a controller. I want to pass "results" array to a twig file and also want to use it through for loop.

Here is my action code in controller

```
public function searchBookAction(Request $request)
{
       $q="PC";
       $conn = $this->get('database_connection');
       $results = $conn->fetchAll("SELECT name FROM products where name like '%".$q."%'");
    return array('results' => $results);
}
```

here is my twig code:

```
{%for data in results%}
<li>{{ data.name|e }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

In this code I get this error:
Variable "results" does not exist in NimoProBundle:Product:product.html.twig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call to use searchBookAction from javascript (as you've ntioned in your comment), I would suggest you to take a look at `JsonResponse`.
What it does is parsing the array into JsonFormat. The json can be decoded by javascript without problems.

In your controller:

```
public function searchBookAction(Request $request)
{
    $q="PC";
    $conn = $this->get('database_connection');
    $results = $conn->fetchAll("SELECT name FROM products where name like '%".$q."%'");
    return new JsonResponse(array('results' => $results);
}
```

In your javascript code (I'm assuming you're using jQuery instead of writing the request by yourself):

```
<script>
$.get('path/to/your/controller', {}, function(response){
    response.results  //<- here you have your results
});
</script>
```

Comment: And little bit confused with 'path/to/your/controller' can you write an example path?

Comment: You can read about "path/to/your/controller/" here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html . It's the URL that will would call the searchBookAction .
What precisely do you mean by using that code in twig? Do you need to have your items on the same page and you need to work with these, or you need a page that produces the results and then you read these from another page?

Comment: I want that Json to be used in my twig page

Comment: Hmm try to update your searchBookAction as I wrote in my comment, then put this in your twig page:
`<script>
var data = 
{{ render(controller('NimoProBundle:CONTROLLER_NAME:searchBook')) |raw }};
alert(data.results.join(','));</script>`
Does it works? Does it returns any error?

Comment: But it is in javascript block I want to use it outside javascript block

Comment: You can use  `{{ render(controller('NimoProBundle:CONTROLLER_NAME:searchBook')) }} ` event without <script>, you can use it everywhere. It will always renders what's in the searchBook method. Is that ok?

Comment: Are you saying after including {{ render(controller('NimoProBundle:CONTROLLER_NAME:searchBook')) }}  line in twig file I can start using $results variable??

Comment: If you want to use the `$results` variable in twig, you have to pass it to the `$this->render` function. In case you don't do that, you won't be able to use that variable. If you have a method that have to be share between multiple controller actions, you can make a function for it (ie: `public function searchBooks()`); then you can take the results from that function and pass these to the `$this->render()` method.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `$this->render()` on controller

```
return $this->render('template.html.twig', array(
    'data' => $results,
));
```

in Twig you did good. Also don't use connection like this. Better use Doctrine ORM for your models.

**Note:**

If you want use render method then you need extend

`Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;`

to do so put

`use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;`

above class name and use `extend` on your class.

You can also use

`class YourController extends Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller`

but it is not pretty solution

This is good lecture for you:

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_view.html
- http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_controller.html

Comment: But I dont want to render the control I just want to return an array simply

Comment: I am calling searchBookAction() from javascript , so I just need $results array to be available on twig page

Comment: then why not to use JSON? then you need `return json_encode($results); ` or use `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse` and add elements in javascript. You can also return HTML to ajax response and it can be done as above.

Comment: How do i get json in javascript?

Comment: via ajax call with jquery you can use getJSON http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want to render anything in your controller:

If the array is **NOT** an entity then you can use [JsonResponse](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/JsonResponse.php) class which turns array into JSON format by serialising it.

In your controller use: `return new JsonResponse(array('name' => $name));`

Then you can either use `resp = JSON.parse(your_json_response);` in your javascript to decode it or just dump in your twig. Or do decoding in twig.

Comment: You're probably doing something wrong/missing along the line. I have been using for long time.